# switch widget for API12

Tags: android

Knowing that the switch widget doesn't work with API < API14, what is the best component that I can use to substitute the Switch widget.
can I use the switch for API>=14 and an other for the others API to keep compatibility?

thx.

Comment: *Can* you have Switch widget before API 14?

Comment: The wohle switch widget requires at least API14 see the reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html therefore it is not possible

Comment: as  Axarydax and  Nickolaus wrote, you can't use `Switch` widget on API# < API14 ...solution is using CheckBox instead ...

Comment: CheckBox is no SwitchWidget^^.... the only thing thats possible is to check the used API version and use either a SwitchWidget or a CheckBox depending on the API level

Comment: @Nickolaus my comment was to your and Axa.. comment not Med Besbes (coz he is wrong) ...

Comment: I am using the switch component and in the Manfest file I'm using
        `android:minSdkVersion="12"`
        `android:targetSdkVersion="17"`

Comment: @Med Besbes, maybe the code gets compiled but have you really tried it on an API 12 device...

Comment: @MedBesbes this app will crash on API12 and API13 devices

Comment: @Nickolaus I don't tried it on an API12
but my code should be compatible with it

Comment: you do not understand how it works ... code is compiled ... but there are no such method/class in Android framework on device ... so you'll get `noclassdeffounderror` or inflater will fail to inflate your layout from xml ...

Comment: @Selvin it's clear now. so I can't use the switch widget for API 12.
Can I at leaste use the Switch for API >= 14 and an other widget for others.

Comment: yes, but it will take more efforts ... better try Nickolaus answer or use CheckBox on all API#

Answer (score 1):

I found a compatibility [solution](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport) that you could try.

Comment: I have not implemented it myself so I can't say anything about it, but I am pretty sure that it works, and I suppose you have done something wrong in your implementation (as I said I found it, not used it), but it doesn't work is not really a problem explanation